# Store meta information as a simple Enum or in database?

Tags: java, database, architecture

I need to store a meta information - this information is really does not affect the system in anyway at all and really just informational purposes.

For example - If I have several applications: ios app, android app, mobile web, desktop web - where a logged in user can create content and the content will be displayed across applications. I was thinking it *may* be useful to store where did that content created from.

So if I have in the database:

```
 - USER table (user_id, username, password, email)
 - CONTENT table (content_id, user_id, content)
```

I want to add the information about where the content came from, so I'll modify the content table as follow:

`- CONTENT table (content_id, user_id, content, source)`

How should I store the source?

1. Should it be just an enum class (i am using Java)

   ```
   public enum Source{ IOS_APP, ANDROID_APP, MOBILE_WEB, DESKTOP_WEB }
   ```

   and then simply store it a String (varchar) in the database?
2. Or, should I actually create an extra table and use foreign key relationship

> ```
> SOURCE table (source_id, source_description)
> CONTENT table (content_id, user_id, content, source_id)
> ```

Which approach would be more desirable? Pros / cons?

The information here reall does not affect the application anyway. In a way, it's just for statistics informational purposes so if we look back for curiosity we can answer the question "where did most of the content come from"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you should not choose one over the other, but instead have both.

The enum will help keep your Java code clean, and the table will help keep that data organized.

It would be good to have a separate (master) table for that type of information. And the other tables can reference it as a foreign key. With that you will have a central location for possible values. You wouldn't have to go every where looking for all the possible values.

You can create an enum representing that (master) table. And it can be used as field type if you create entities for other tables. You can see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) for an example. Also (optionally) you could valid the enum with table content at application start, to make sure the enum stays in sync with the table, in case new values or added or some existing ones are updated.

Comment: But when I have it both, wouldn't a problem be that there's no real connection between the table and the enum? ie. I can add / modify entries on the db table without changing the enum class and vice versa, there's no constraint between the 2

Comment: That's why I said "Also (optionally) you could valid the enum with table content at application start ..." in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have enums in the code and a table with the data represented by the enum in the database. Also, I make the IDs in the table to match with the value of the enum and have easy access to well-known enum values.

Another approach is not having an enum, but a class with ID + Name (maybe the enum exists anyway, to match the IDs with the enum values and have easy access to well-known enum values). If you have code like "if myEnum = MyEnum.SomeValue then" (this is, you have to take a decision on an enum value) maybe it's better to have polimorphic behavior using the class.

PS: I'm not a Java developer, I work with C#, I think that enums in Java are actually real classes that are able to have behaviour, aren't they?